# Can I register DNS under an IP with a subdomain on 1&1?

Tags: dns, domain-registration, 1and1

I have a server on the website `www.example.com`, and I want to register another domain like `www.examplehelp.com` with DNS from `www.example.com/help`. Can I do something like this on 1&1 domain registration?

Comment: If you move www.example.com/help to help.example.com you can then create a CNAME record for www.examplehelp.com to help.example.com

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess redirect. No registration.

Comment: Would you post some example code which works

Comment: The comment above is the more appropriate method, as the CNAME is returned with an NSLOOKUP, and your 301 redirect only works on Apache Based Hosts, whereas the CNAME is independent of the server software